# Vuetify AppBar and Navigation drawer and nested Routes

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a vue/vuetify (v2) application that has a login page (without toolbar/drawer) and other pages(with toolbar/drawer). That is why I started to use nested routes. But unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do it properly. And page is falling apart.
Here image 1. show what I want to achieve and image 2. shows what i get.
[image]

My `routes.ts`:

```
{
    path: '/auth',
    component: Authenticated,
    meta: {requiresAuth: true},
    children: [
        {
            path: 'home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home,
            meta: {requiresAuth: true},
        },
    ]
},
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
},
```

My `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
    <snackbar/>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And my `Authenticated.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar dense dark class="primary">
        ...
    </v-app-bar>

        <v-navigation-drawer permanent  clipped>
        ...
        </v-navigation-drawer>

    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm doing this the right way but I achieved this by checking if there was a user un session, so my `App.vue` looks like this :

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <t-nav v-if="$store.getters.userInSession"></t-nav>
    <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And then my custom `t-nav` component is like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar :color="grey" short app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="toggleMenu" class="white--text"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{ currentRouteName | uppercase }}</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer
        app
        color="dark"
        dark
        v-model="showMenu"
        mobile-breakpoint="500"
    >
    </v-navigation-drawer>

  </div>
</template>
```

It's quite the same as your code, except that you're trying to put your nav inside the main with the `router-view` and not outside.